# In R shiny, a dropdown widget shows itself when it is updated

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I can't produce an example because the code is pretty large and complex.

But there is a `selectInput` widget that is hidden, via `shinyjs::hide`. But when I call the `updateSelectInput` function to change the values of this widget, it shows itself.

Has anyone encountered a situation like this? Just by merely updating the widget should not cause it to reappear.

Comment: Try to find a minimal code example that shows this behaviour, otherwise it's difficult to help you. Thanks!

Comment: I have to agree with starja. I tried but I cannot replicate this.

Comment: Apparently this is an issue with Shiny 1.4. It is fixed in Shiny 1.5.